# php, gd, color switching with antialiasing and shadows

Tags: php, colors, gd, shadow, antialiasing

I want to make a wordpress theme with a color picker to switch the main color(s) of the theme.
At some points of the theme the colors I want to change could be in images - maybe when it comes to rounded corners, overlapping stuff or anything else that couldn't be easily done in plain CSS.

I planned to take care of those things using a color switching function in GD. However, as I have basically no experience with GD I first wanted to make sure if those color switching functions can take care of shadows, antialiasing and stuff like that. The examples I found yet all just changed one plain color to another plain color.

Is there a trick to do that with GD and if yes, can you give me a link to a tutorial or a good example?

Thank you!

Comment: the way to go is probably to calculate the hsb value from rgb... don't know how exactly however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better to replace all those fixed-color-antialias images with .png images with appropriate transparency set on any bits that need to be merged with the background. That way you only have one set of images for the theme, instead of one-set-per-color-scheme, which could quickly get unmanageable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I am still planning my theme, I can do that :) However - how would I change red to blue in an image like this (or in two overlayed images) http://is.gd/jtTtp

Comment: For a simple gradient like that, it's relatively trivial. Just get the rgb value at each pixel and swap the red and blue values. `imagecoloarat()` and `imagecolorset()` But that doesn't work for a "real" image - you'd just mangle it.

Comment: hm, I'm not planning to manipulate "real" images like photos. However, I wouldn't always want to change red to blue - it could also be red to some other color.

Comment: pure color -> pure color is trivial. But moving (say) beige to cyan isn't, especially if there's multiple shades of both.

Comment: in fact I wouldn't need to move one mixed color to another - would it work with a pure color moving to a mixed color?

Comment: Sure, but how would you determine which mixed color to use? THat's the non-trivial part.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of colorize algorithms:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

You should also find something nice in google searching for "php colorize"

Comment: Thanks you! Looks like img_filter_colorize() can do the job BUT ONLY when the image only has one color (it's quite similar to img_filter_grayscale). However when I have an image with two different colors (for example a red shaded square and a green shaded square) img_filter_colorize will change both of them, not just one. Is there a solution?

Comment: Yes, that's true. If you have an image with two colours you have to split it to one-color images and then colorize independently using 2 colours. Eg. First image => pink, second image => black. You can also split the image to two and then colorize and merge back in php (check imagealphablending, imagesavealpha).  You can do this, done this myself for one theme. You just supply 3 colours to the generator (menu, text, background) and all elements (like buttons, lists, etc.) gets generated automatically